# Why does this cfscript function work?

Tags: coldfusion, character-encoding, cfml, bluedragon

I wrote this function, the last line seems wrong* but it actually works. Can someone explain how does this stuff work ?

```
function convertEncoding(str,from,to) {
    var charSetObj = createobject("java", "java.nio.charset.Charset");
    var e_to = charsetObj.forName(from);
    var e_from = charsetObj.forName(to);
    return e_from.decode(e_to.encode(str)).toString();
}
```

I am on BlueDragon 7 and 7.1JX (not the open source)

I was inspired from this function : http://acoderslife.com/index.cfm/blog/Converting-Text-From-UTF-8-to-ISO-8859-1

<sup>* It seems that our last action is to work with the From encoding. It should be From.decode(string) and then To.encode(decoded_string)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it seems off is that you swapped the variable names, so they do not accurately represent the contents:

- var e_**to** = charsetObj.forName(**from**); // Original encoding
- var e_**from** = charsetObj.forName(**to**); // New encoding

The reason it works is because the final statement accounts for this by swapping the variables positions, so that despite their names, the code is actually doing this:

```
   return newEncoding.decode( originalEncoding.encode(str) ).toString();
```

Obviously best to fix the variable names, so you are not scratching your head when you run across this code six months from now.

```
function convertEncoding(str, from, to) {
    var charSetObj = createobject("java", "java.nio.charset.Charset");
    var origEncoding = charsetObj.forName( arguments.from );
    var newEncoding = charsetObj.forName( arguments.to );
    return newEncoding.decode(origEncoding.encode( arguments.str )).toString();
}
```

Comment: aaaaw how could i have missed it ... thank you ! what bugs me is that the original function (see my link) actually works too. Thanks again

Comment: Oh, right. I did not notice it the first time, but the variable names are essentially swapped in the blog entry too. Hence the confusion!